# load_plugin_textdomain error

Tags: plugins, functions

I receive this error while debug mode is enabled:

> Notice: load_plugin_textdomain was called with an argument that is
>   deprecated since version 2.7 with no alternative available. in
>   /home/xyz/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3739

I found that is related to this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-smilies-se/

I really need to have this plugin and would not ignore it; Also plugin author had not responded about this issue.
Could you please guide me to modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin calling `load_plugin_textdomain()` [the wrong way](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97928/73):

```
load_plugin_textdomain(
    'custom_smilies', 
    PLUGINDIR . '/' . dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)) . '/lang'
);
```

You have to change the code to:

```
load_plugin_textdomain(
    'custom_smilies', 
    false,
    plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/lang'
);
```

Comment: plugin_dir_path() returns a trailing slash though.

Comment: the final argument should look like this: 'your-plugin-dir-name/languages/'

So, ` dirname( plugin_basename( file_magic_const ) ) . '/languages' ` should do the trick but note that the value of __FILE__ can differ depending upon it location of call. So, best option is to call this function from main plugin file.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
function clcs_add_pages() {
    add_options_page(__('Smilies Options', 'custom_smilies'), __('Smilies', 'custom_smilies'), 8, CLCSABSFILE, 'clcs_options_admin_page');
}
```

to this code

```
function clcs_add_pages() {
    add_options_page(__('Smilies Options', 'custom_smilies'), __('Smilies', 'custom_smilies'), 'manage_network_plugins', CLCSABSFILE, 'clcs_options_admin_page');
}
```

and solved! @toscho